# Pulling dbdata file with not rooted device

Tags: adb, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s, backup, broken-screen

The screen of my Galaxy S is broken, so I can't see anything and the touchscreen doesn't work. After a while, I managed to get everything I needed from the `/sdcard` folder with adb.

Now I have some very important things in my Memo app that I would like to save, but the problem is that my phone is not rooted, so I can't pull anything from dbdata folder.

So, long story short: I need to pull a file from `/dbdata` but I have no root permissions on my phone, and the data I need to save is not from a debuggable app (it's the `.ab` data of the original Memo app). Is there any way to do it? If not, is there any way to root my phone without having to interact with it, since my touchscreen doesn't work anymore?
(I already tried with run-as but as I already told, the app is not debuggable)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which Android version is running on your device. With < 4.0, chances are close to zero: without root access, you cannot access those places.

With 4.0 and up, you *theoretically* would have the possibility to use `adb backup` (see e.g. our [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)). Thing is, you have to approve that from your device by tapping "OK" on the authentication popup – which is not possible with a broken screen.

TL;DR: It's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... yeah I forgot! It's android 2.3, so it's not possible I see. But is there really no way to have a copy of those files? I mean, isn't there any way to change my phone's kernel or root it without having to tap anything on the touchscreen? I wouldn't insist so much if those weren't important files.

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of, sorry.